# Flutter entering to sub-sub collection in firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, collections

my nested collections looks like this:

```
User--> drugs--> drugsTime
```

I want to update data in document in the subsub-collection (drugsTime)
however I dont know the drug document id and the drugtime document id
so I did the following :

```
 ConfirmDrugTaken(DateTime d) async {
    final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final _uid = user?.uid;
    var drugID="";
    // Get the user's sub-collections in Firestore
    final QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot =
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(_uid)
        .collection('drug').where("drugName", isEqualTo: widget.title)
        .get();
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) async {
      drugID=element.id;
    });

    final QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot2 =FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(_uid)
        .collection("drug")
        .doc(drugID).collection("drugDates").where('time',isEqualTo: d).get() as QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>;
    querySnapshot2.docs.forEach((element) async {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc(_uid)
          .collection("drug")
          .doc(drugID).collection("drugDates").doc(element.id).update( {'isTaken': true});

    });


  }
```

but this error occur:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' is not a subtype of type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast
E/flutter (17976): #0      _drugSetupState.ConfirmDrugTaken (package:taafi_application_v1/pages/drug_setup.dart:215:79)
E/flutter (17976): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17976): #1      _drugSetupState.setAlarm.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:taafi_application_v1/pages/drug_setup.dart:112:20)
E/flutter (17976): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Is there is another way to enter to the sub-sub-collection with out knowing the id OR how can I fix this error?

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use `await` to call async method, code should be as follows for `querySnapshot2`

```
final QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot2 = (await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(_uid)
        .collection("drug")
        .doc(drugID).collection("drugDates").where('time',isEqualTo: d).get()) as QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works Sir, but what if i want to retrieve all document in the  drugsTime collection?
i did the same steps until querySnapshot2 but this error occur  'Unhandled Exception: type '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast'

Comment: It might be causing in different place, can you help me by adding you code of other queries

Comment: here it is Sir, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75439908/flutter-retrieve-all-documents-in-the-sub-sub-collection-in-firebase)

Comment: I guess, you added new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75439908/flutter-retrieve-all-documents-in-the-sub-sub-collection-in-firebase, please and whole file content of `drug_setup.dart`

Comment: yes Sir, I did that. Can you refer to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75439908/flutter-retrieve-all-documents-in-the-sub-sub-collection-in-firebase