# Flutter retrieve all documents in the sub-sub-Collection in firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, collections

my nested collections looks like this:

```
User--> drugs--> drugsTime
```

I want to retrieve all the documents in the subsub-collection (drugsTime) for specific drug however I dont know the drug document id so I did the following :

```
getData() async {
    final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final _uid = user?.uid;
    var drugID = "";
    final QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot =
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(_uid)
        .collection('drug')
        .where("drugName", isEqualTo: widget.title)
        .get();
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) async {
      drugID = element.id;
    });
    final QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot2  = (await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(_uid)
        .collection("drug")
        .doc(drugID)
        .get()) as QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>;
    querySnapshot2.docs.forEach((element) async {
      drugTime .add (element.get('time'));
      isTaken.add(element.get("isTaken"));
    });

    print(drugTime);
    print(isTaken);
  }
```

but this error ocurr:

```
E/flutter (24517): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast
E/flutter (24517): #0      _historyState.getData (package:taafi_application_v1/pages/history.dart:38:17)
E/flutter (24517): <asynchronous suspension>
```

the problem shows in

```
as QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>;
```

how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here, you casted `DocumentSnapshot` with `QuerySnapshot`, `where` will return `QuerySnapshot` and `doc` will return `DocumentSnapshot`.

Your code of method `getData` should be as following

```
getData() async {
  final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  final _uid = user?.uid;
  var drugID = "";
  final QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot =
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(_uid)
      .collection('drug')
      .where("drugName", isEqualTo: widget.title)
      .get();
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) async {
    drugID = element.id;
  });
  final DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc  = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(_uid)
      .collection("drug")
      .doc(drugID)
      .get();
  drugTime.add (doc.data()!['time']);//Make sure time has value
  isTaken.add(doc.data()!['isTaken']);

  print(drugTime);
  print(isTaken);
}
```

Please make sure of which you are requested for.

Comment: I tried it but it shows this error:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Comment: Add next line of error log

Comment: I added it in the question because it is too long

Comment: Edited in answer, make sure document has proper value of `time` and `isToken`, if not sure then use with conditional null checker `doc.data()?['time'] ?? default value`

Comment: Now the error is gone, i checked there is data in document and checked the the values. but there is nothing retrieved, post an image of the firestore

Comment: How many `drug`'s you are having with same name?

Comment: neither, no duplicate item in the firestore

Comment: If you are having multiple drugs with same name, then `doc` has to be initialised inside `forEach`

Comment: I'm not seeing where you are using `drugTime` and `isTaken` in build to render in UI.

Comment: I still working on them, i just want to retrieve data first

Comment: Add success log